# SwiftUI - Unable to reference @Published value outside Struct

Tags: struct, swiftui

I am new to `SwiftUI` and am hoping for some assistance with a project I am developing.

I am unable to reference `@published` value outside a struct.
All values are correctly functioning within the struct using:

1. `@ObservableObject`
2. `@Publihsed`
3. `@ObservedObject`

I have a Struct within `ContentView` which is linked to another View where I would like to display Quantity and Costs.
I have attempted various ways to access the values as can be seen in the struct `NewOrders`, but I keep getting zero and not getting the updated value.
Am I missing a step or executing code incorrectly?

Thanks in advance

```
class MealOrders: ObservableObject {

    //Jollof Rice - Published
    @Published var jollof = 0

    //Swallow - Published
    @Published var swallow = 0

    //Pepper Soup - Published
    @Published var pepperSoup = 0

}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

              VStack {
                NavigationView {

                    Section {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                        NavigationLink(destination: MenuOption()) {
                        Text("Meal Options")
                    }

                        Spacer()
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 
                        .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)

                        }.padding() //Vstack End

                    }
                    Section {

                        VStack {

                            Image("africanfoods")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 275.0, height: 250.0)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 5))
                                .scaledToFit()

                        }


                    } //Section End

                    Section { //Social Media

                        VStack {
                            Spacer()

                            HStack {
                            Spacer()
                                Image("facebook")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width:40, height: 40)
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .padding()

                                Image("instergram")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width:40, height: 40)
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .padding()


                                Image("youtube")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width:40, height: 40)
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .padding()

                                Image("twitter")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width:40, height: 40)
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                        .padding(.horizontal, 50)

                        }

                    } //Vstack End
                } //Social Media
                    .navigationBarTitle(Text("African Foods Center"))

            }   //NavView End
    } //VStack End
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct MenuOption: View {

    //Object Observed Declarations
    @ObservedObject var meals = MealOrders()

    //Meal Prices
    @State private var jolloRiceUnitCost = 14.95 //Jollof Rice Unit Cost

    @State private var swallowUnitCost = 12.50 //Swallow Unit Cost

    @State private var pepperSoupUnitCost = 13.50 //Pepper Soup Unit Cost

    @State private var deliveryCost = 5.99 //Delivery Cost


    @State private var menuItem = 0

    var menuItems = ["Rice Meals", "Swallow Meals", "Pepper Soups"]


    //Meals Calculator
    var calculateMeal: Double {

        var orderCost = 0.0

        //Jollof Rice
        if menuItems[menuItem] == "Rice Meals" {
             orderCost = self.jolloRiceUnitCost * Double(self.meals.jollof)
                return orderCost

        //Swallow - Pounded Yam / Eba
        } else if menuItems[menuItem] == "Swallow Meals" {
            orderCost = self.swallowUnitCost * Double(self.meals.swallow)

        } else if menuItems[menuItem] == "Pepper Soups" {
            orderCost = self.pepperSoupUnitCost * Double(self.meals.pepperSoup)

        }

            return orderCost
    }


    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            Section(header: Text("Select Meal").padding(.horizontal, 25)) {

                Picker("Select Item", selection: $menuItem) {
                             ForEach(0 ..< menuItems.count) {
                                 Text(self.menuItems[$0])

                             }
                         }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
                          .padding(.horizontal, 25)

                         if menuItems[menuItem] == "Rice Meals" {
                             Text("Rice Meals:")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 25)

                            Spacer().frame(height:20)
                                `Text("Rice meals consist of Jollof Rice, Rice and Stew, Fried 
                            Rice. You can option in meat, fish and or plantain with any of the meals")`
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .lineLimit(nil)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 25)

                            Spacer().frame(height:60)

                                //Insert image - Jollof Rice
                                Image("jollofRice")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width:250, height: 250)
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .border(Color.black, width: 4)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 100)

                            Spacer().frame(height:20)

                            HStack {
                            Stepper("Quantity (Max 5)",value: $meals.jollof, in: 0...5)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 45)
                                Text("\(meals.jollof): £\(calculateMeal, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                .padding()

                            }.padding()


                            Section { //Button Order

                                VStack {//Add Stepper for Quantity
                                    Spacer()

                                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 140) {
                                        Spacer()
                                        Button(action: {}) {

                                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Jollof::  \(meals.jollof), £\(calculateMeal, specifier:  "%.2f")")) {
                                                Text("Create Order")
                                                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                                                    .padding()
                                                    .background(Color.blue)
                                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                    .cornerRadius(6)

                                            }.padding()
                                            Spacer()

                                        }
                                    }


                                } //Vstack End


                            } //Button Section End

                         } else if menuItems[menuItem] == "Swallow Meals" {
                             Text("Swallow")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 25)

                            Spacer().frame(height:20)
                                `Text("Swallow is the colloqual word for Pounded Yam, Eba, Fufu or Amala. This is complemented with soups, such as Egusi, Okra etc. You could have this meal with either meat or fish")`

                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .lineLimit(nil)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 25)

                            Spacer().frame(height:60)

                                //Inset Image
                                Image("poundedYamEgusi")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width:250, height:250)
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .border(Color.black, width: 4)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 100)

                            HStack {//Add Stepper for Quantity
                                Stepper("Quantity (Max 5)",value: $meals.swallow, in: 0...5)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 45)
                                Text("\(meals.swallow): £\(calculateMeal, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                .padding()
                            }.padding()


                            //Insert Order Button
                            Section {

                                VStack {

                                    Spacer()

                                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 140) {
                                        Spacer()
                                            Button(action: {}) {

                                                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Swallow:  \(meals.swallow), £\(calculateMeal, specifier:  "%.2f")")) {
                                                    Text("Create Order")
                                                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                                                        .padding()
                                                        .background(Color.blue)
                                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                        .cornerRadius(6)

                                                }.padding()
                                                Spacer()
                                            }
                                    }

                                } //VStack End


                            } //Section End

                         } else if menuItems[menuItem] == "Pepper Soups" {
                             Text("Pepper Soup")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 25)

                            Spacer().frame(height:20)
                                `Text("Pepper soup is normally taken after one has had either Pounded Yam or rice meals. Depending on the audeience, the soup can be lightly spicy to very hot. Pepper soup can be had with either fish or meat")`
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .lineLimit(nil)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 25)

                            Spacer().frame(height:60)

                            //Insert Image
                            Image("pepperSoupYam")
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width:250, height:250)
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .border(Color.black, width: 4)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 100)

                            HStack {//Add Stepper Quantity for Pepper Soup
                                Stepper("Quantity (5 Max)",value: $meals.pepperSoup, in: 0...5)
                                    .padding(.horizontal, 45)
                                Text("\(meals.pepperSoup): £\(calculateMeal, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                .padding()

                            }.padding()

                            //Inset Order Button
                            Section {

                                VStack {

                                    Spacer()

                                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 140) {
                                        Spacer()

                                        Button(action: {}) {

                                            NavigationLink(destination: NewOrders()) {
                                                Text("Create Order")
                                                .font(.system(size: 14))
                                                .padding()
                                                .background(Color.blue)
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                .cornerRadius(6)

                                            }.padding()
                                            Spacer()
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                         }

                         Spacer()

            }.font(.system(size: 14))
             .foregroundColor(.purple)

            } //Vstack Ending


    } //View Ending
}


//This sis going to be the Orders Struct
struct NewOrders: View {

    @ObservedObject var orderUpdatedV2 = MealOrders()

    @State private var orderUpdate = MenuOption().meals.jollof

    var  body: some View {

        //let mealsU: ContentView

        NavigationView{

            VStack {

                List {

                    Text("")

                }

            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("Meal Order")
    }

}
```

Comment: You're likely to get better help if you trim down the code in your post.

Comment: Are you referring to the view `NewOrders` that is not getting populated after adding the quantity from the options.

Answer (score 0):

This line below is incorrect because creates new value, that's why you have `nil`

```
@State private var orderUpdate = MenuOption().meals.jollof
```

instead you need to have (as far as I understood your code)

```
@Binding var orderUpdate: Int
```

and pass it in place of creating

```
NavigationLink(destination: NewOrders(orderUpdate: $meals.jollof)) {
```

*Note*: This is the idea, I'm not sure copy/paste will work, because provided your code snapshot is not compilable at my side.

Comment: Glad to hear that! ))